# multiple email validate errro in if i used number

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

HI i m using to this code for multiple email validate .

ex. if i test to this  email id `rohitazadkumw@gmail.com`, `rowkujerr@gmail.com` **then it's working fine** .

but if i used to this email id `rohit2345@gmail.com`, `rohit.azad2345@gmail.com`  **then it's show to error can u tell  me where i m wrong this code .**

```js
var validEmailValue = [];
var nonValidEmailValue = [];

function checkEmail(email) {
  var regExp = /(^[a-z]([a-z_\.]*)@([a-z_\.]*)([.][a-z]{2,4})$)|(^[a-z]([a-z_\.]*)@([a-z_\.]*)(\.[a-z]{3})(\.[a-z]{2})*$)/i;
  return regExp.test(email);
}


function checkEmails(textareaId) {
  var textId = textareaId;
  var emails = document.getElementById(textId).value;
  emails = emails.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  document.getElementById(textId).value = emails;
  var emailArray = emails.split(",");
  for (i = 0; i <= (emailArray.length - 1); i++) {
    if (checkEmail(emailArray[i])) {
      validEmailValue.push([emailArray[i]]);
    } else {
      nonValidEmailValue.push([emailArray[i]]);
    }
  }
}




$('#testEmailIDs').live('blur', function() {
  validEmailValue = [];
  nonValidEmailValue = [];
  checkEmails('testEmailIDs');
  if (nonValidEmailValue == '') {
    alert('email Validate');
  } else {
    alert('not vallidate');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="testEmailIDs"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression does not have numeric checks:

```
var regExp = /(^[a-z0-9]([a-z_\.0-9]*)@([a-z_\.]*)([.][a-z]{2,4})$)|(^[a-z0-9]([a-z_\.0-9]*)@([a-z_\.]*)(\.[a-z]{3})(\.[a-z]{2})*$)/i;
```

```js
var validEmailValue = [];
var nonValidEmailValue = [];

function checkEmail(email) {
  var regExp = /(^[a-z0-9]([a-z_\.0-9]*)@([a-z_\.]*)([.][a-z]{2,4})$)|(^[a-z0-9]([a-z_\.0-9]*)@([a-z_\.]*)(\.[a-z]{3})(\.[a-z]{2})*$)/i;
  return regExp.test(email);
}


function checkEmails(textareaId) {
  var textId = textareaId;
  var emails = document.getElementById(textId).value;
  emails = emails.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  document.getElementById(textId).value = emails;
  var emailArray = emails.split(",");
  for (i = 0; i <= (emailArray.length - 1); i++) {
    if (checkEmail(emailArray[i])) {
      validEmailValue.push([emailArray[i]]);
    } else {
      nonValidEmailValue.push([emailArray[i]]);
    }
  }
}




$('#testEmailIDs').live('blur', function() {
  validEmailValue = [];
  nonValidEmailValue = [];
  checkEmails('testEmailIDs');
  if (nonValidEmailValue == '') {
    alert('email Validate');
  } else {
    alert('not vallidate');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="testEmailIDs" autofocus>aaa-123@gmail.com</textarea>
```

Comment: can you update code for the numeric values in domain name;

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute `RegExp` for using `.checkValidity()` at hidden `<input type="email">` element to check each email separated by space at `textarea` element with `Array.prototype.every()` callback. If each email returns `true` at `.checkValidity()` following setting `.val()` to split text, call `alert()` with parameter `"email validate"`, else with parameter `"email not validate"`.

```js
$("#testEmailIDs").blur(function() { 
  alert("email " + (!this.value.split(/\s+/).every(function(val) {
    return $("input[hidden]").val(val)[0].checkValidity()
  }) ? "not " : "") + "validate")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="email" hidden />
<textarea id="testEmailIDs"></textarea>
```